# iPhone 5 screenshots not showing on iPhone 5 App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I updated my app for the iPhone 5, but the 3.5" screenshots are still showing on the iPhone 5 App Store. It has been suggested that this is due to not building for armv7s. Te app is therefore not listed as optimized for iPhone 5, and the associated screenshots are not used.

Does anyone have the same experience, and can confirm that this is the flag used by the App Store? I'm under the impression that many devs had to delay including armv7s, and am surprised that there aren't more reports of this issue.

Comment: No, not building for armv7s shouldn't affect the screenshots. I can confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Add launch image **Default-568h@2x.png** to your resources.
It tells to iTunes Store that "This app is optimized for iPhone 5".
Good luck!